# Dataframe how to keep only unique rows and plot curve

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data frame where I am trying to actually plot a curve but the problem is that it has multiple corresponding values for each value in both precision and recall.

```
       precision  recall
1       0.000000       0
7       0.000000       0
23      0.000000       0
28      0.000000       0
34      0.000000       0
35      0.000000       0
40      0.000000       0
50      0.000000       0
60      0.000000       0
17859   0.133333  0.009050
13159   0.066667  0.012195
9232    0.133333  0.012500
6131    0.066667  0.013333
7900    0.066667  0.014085
11671   0.066667  0.014925
20317   0.066667  0.014925
```

I want to keep the unique rows considering above data set keeping unique in my interpretation of unique would be:

```
       precision  recall
1       0.000000       0
17859   0.133333  0.009050
13159   0.066667  0.012195
9232    0.133333  0.012500
6131    0.066667  0.013333
7900    0.066667  0.014085
20317   0.066667  0.014925
```

How can I convert my original data frame to obtain above unique rows?

I tried grouping approach:

```
grouped = df.groupby(cols_to_consider)
index = [gp_keys[0] for gp_keys in grouped.groups.values()]
unique_df = df.reindex(index)
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [drop_duplicates()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to remove duplicate rows.

```
In [49]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[49]:
       precision    recall
1       0.000000  0.000000
17859   0.133333  0.009050
13159   0.066667  0.012195
9232    0.133333  0.012500
6131    0.066667  0.013333
7900    0.066667  0.014085
11671   0.066667  0.014925
```

Also, your method should work, I guess column_names must be messed up?

```
In [57]: grouped = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist())

In [58]: index = [gp_keys[0] for gp_keys in grouped.groups.values()]

In [59]: unique_df = df.reindex(index)

In [60]: unique_df
Out[60]:
       precision    recall
1       0.000000  0.000000
11671   0.066667  0.014925
6131    0.066667  0.013333
7900    0.066667  0.014085
17859   0.133333  0.009050
9232    0.133333  0.012500
13159   0.066667  0.012195
```